# beamer block as wide as the entire page

Tags: beamer, positioning, block, beamer-metropolis

How can I have a full-paperwidth beamer `block` in the example below?
How can I then control its vertical position across the slide?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
\centering
\vfill

\metroset{block=fill}
\begin{block}{\vspace*{-3ex}}
\centering
A wide block
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source of the metropolis theme ([here](https://github.com/matze/mtheme/blob/master/source/beamerinnerthememetropolis.dtx#L386)), you see that the `block` environment is made up of several `beamercolorbox` environments. These take `wd={width}` as an optional argument to resize them to your desired width. So just add `wd=\paperwidth` to every occurence of `beamercolorbox` in the `\metropolis@block` macro.

The following example shows two things:

- First, I redefine `\metropolis@block` to have a `wd=\metropolis@blockwd` as argument for every `beamercolorbox`. The length `\metropolis@blockwd` is set to `\paperwidth`, but you could choose any other value you like.
- Second, for the placement of the `block` environment on the slide: You might want to consider using the `t` option on the frame. Enabling it, elements on the slide are not vertically centered but placed starting at the top of the slide. I feel it's easier this way to reach proper placement of the `block` by using `\vpsace*{2cm}` (with any value you like).

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\metropolis@blockwd}
\setlength{\metropolis@blockwd}{\paperwidth}
\renewcommand{\metropolis@block}[1]{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title#1}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[rightskip=0pt plus 4em,wd=\metropolis@blockwd]{block title#1}}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[rightskip=0pt plus 4em,wd=\metropolis@blockwd]{block title#1}%
  }%
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[
      sep=\dimexpr\metropolis@blocksep-\metropolis@blockadjust\relax,
      leftskip=\metropolis@blockadjust,
      rightskip=\dimexpr\metropolis@blockadjust plus 4em\relax,
      wd=\metropolis@blockwd
    ]{block title#1}%
  }}%
      \usebeamerfont*{block title#1}%
      \metropolis@strut%
      \insertblocktitle%
      \metropolis@strut%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body#1}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[vmode,wd=\paperwidth]{block body#1}}{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[vmode,wd=\paperwidth]{block body#1}%
  }{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=\metropolis@blocksep, vmode,wd=\metropolis@blockwd]{block body#1}%
    \vspace{-\metropolis@parskip}
  }}%
      \usebeamerfont{block body#1}%
      \setlength{\parskip}{\metropolis@parskip}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame}
\centering
\vspace*{2cm}
\metroset{block=fill}
\begin{block}{\vspace*{-3ex}}
\centering
A wide block
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it allowed my to modify all of the existing `blocks` in one go, but all the answer are equally good!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps not the best solution, but lying about the `\linewidth` using a `minipage` with width `\paperwidth` does work. The `\makebox[\linwidth][c]` is to give everything the width of `\linewidth` and centre-align it.

For the vertical placement you can change the argument given to `\vspace*`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}          
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
\centering
\vspace*{5cm}
\metroset{block=fill}
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\paperwidth}
    \begin{block}{\vspace*{-3ex}}
    \centering
    A wide block 
    \end{block}
  \end{minipage}
}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use one column that spans the whole `\paperwidth`. For vertical alignment, as in the other answers, use the option `[t]` for the frame to top align, and then push down with e.g. `\vspace*{}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{\paperwidth}
      \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
      \metroset{block=fill}
      \begin{block}{\vspace*{-3ex}}
        \centering
        A wide block
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]